# ConcurrentModificationException with MockRestService when restTemplate used via async executors

Tags: java, rest, asynchronous, spring-boot, spring-web

Trying to mock out rest responses with spring's `MockRestService` for integration tests, but `AbstractRequestExpectationManager` keeps running into `ConcurrentModificationException` when the actual code uses rest template asynchronously.

Test pseudocode snippets:

```
@Autowired
RestTemplate restTemplate;
MockRestServiceServer mockRestServiceServer;

@Test
public test() {
    // given
    mockRestServiceServer = MockRestServiceServer
            .bindTo( restTemplate )
            .ignoreExpectOrder()  // supported from spring 4.3
            .build();
    prepareRestResponse( "/resource/url", "mock json content".getBytes() );
    // when
    myservice.refreshPricesForProductGroup( 2 );

    // then
    // assertions
}

private void prepareRestResponse( final String urlTail, final byte[] responseContent ) {
    mockRestServiceServer
            .expect( requestTo( endsWith( urlTail ) ) )
            .andExpect( method( HttpMethod.GET ) )
            .andRespond( withSuccess()
                    .body( responseContent )
                    .contentType( APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8 ) );
}
```

Actual code accessing the rest template:

```
@Autowired
Executor executor
@Autowired
PriceRestClient priceClient
@Autowired
ProductRestClient productClient

/../

private void refreshPricesForProductGroup( final int groupId ) {

    List<Product> products = productClient.findAllProductsForGroup( groupId );

    products.forEach( p ->
            executor.execute( () -> {
                final Price price = priceClient.getPrice( p.getId() );
                priceRepository.updatePrice( price );
            } )
    );
}
```

The PriceRestClient.getPrice() performs simple rest call:

```
Price getPrice( String productId ) {

    try {
        ResponseEntity<byte[]> entity = restTemplate.exchange(
                restUtil.getProductPriceDataUrl(),
                HttpMethod.GET,
                restUtil.createGzipEncodingRequestEntity(),
                byte[].class,
                productId );

        if ( entity.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK ) {
            String body = restUtil.unmarshalGzipBody( entity.getBody() );
            return priceEntityParser.parse( body );
        }

    } catch ( HttpClientErrorException e ) {
        // TODO
    } catch ( ResourceAccessException e ) {
        // TODO
    } catch ( IOException e ) {
        // TODO
    }

    return null;
}
```

thrown exception:

```
Exception in thread "AsyncExecutor-2" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashIterator.nextNode(LinkedHashMap.java:711)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedKeyIterator.next(LinkedHashMap.java:734)
    at org.springframework.test.web.client.AbstractRequestExpectationManager$RequestExpectationGroup.findExpectation(AbstractRequestExpectationManager.java:167)
    at org.springframework.test.web.client.UnorderedRequestExpectationManager.validateRequestInternal(UnorderedRequestExpectationManager.java:42)
    at org.springframework.test.web.client.AbstractRequestExpectationManager.validateRequest(AbstractRequestExpectationManager.java:71)
    at org.springframework.test.web.client.MockRestServiceServer$MockClientHttpRequestFactory$1.executeInternal(MockRestServiceServer.java:286)
    at org.springframework.mock.http.client.MockClientHttpRequest.execute(MockClientHttpRequest.java:93)
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:93)
    at com.mycompany.myproduct.web.client.HttpRequestInterceptorLoggingClient.interceptReq(HttpRequestInterceptorLoggingClient.java:32)
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:85)
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:69)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:596)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:557)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:475)
    at com.mycompany.myproduct.rest.PriceRestClient.getPrice(PriceRestClient.java:48)
    at com.mycompany.myproduct.service.ProductPriceSourcingService.lambda$null$29(ProductPriceSourcingService.java:132)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Am I doing something wrong here, or it might be a bug with MockRestService?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Fixed" this by creating a copy of `UnorderedRequestExpectationManager`:

```
package cucumber.testbeans;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpRequest;
import org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpResponse;
import org.springframework.test.web.client.*;

/**
* Essentially an {@link UnorderedRequestExpectationManager}, but overrides some implementations of {@link AbstractRequestExpectationManager}
* in order to allow adding more expectations after the first request has been made.
*/
public class RestRequestExpectationManager extends AbstractRequestExpectationManager {

    private final RequestExpectationGroup remainingExpectations = new RequestExpectationGroup();

    @Override
    public ResponseActions expectRequest( ExpectedCount count, RequestMatcher matcher ) {
        //        Assert.state(getRequests().isEmpty(), "Cannot add more expectations after actual requests are made.");
        RequestExpectation expectation = new DefaultRequestExpectation( count, matcher );
        getExpectations().add( expectation );
        return expectation;
    }

    @Override
    public ClientHttpResponse validateRequest( ClientHttpRequest request ) throws IOException {
        //        if (getRequests().isEmpty()) {
        afterExpectationsDeclared();
        //        }
        ClientHttpResponse response = validateRequestInternal( request );
        getRequests().add( request );
        return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void afterExpectationsDeclared() {
        this.remainingExpectations.updateAll( getExpectations() );
    }

    @Override
    public ClientHttpResponse validateRequestInternal( ClientHttpRequest request ) throws IOException {
        RequestExpectation expectation = this.remainingExpectations.findExpectation( request );
        if ( expectation != null ) {
            ClientHttpResponse response = expectation.createResponse( request );
            this.remainingExpectations.update( expectation );
            return response;
        }
        throw createUnexpectedRequestError( request );
    }

    /**
    * Same as {@link AbstractRequestExpectationManager.RequestExpectationGroup}, but synchronizes operations on the {@code expectations}
    * set, so async operation would be possible.
    */
    private static class RequestExpectationGroup {

        private final Set<RequestExpectation> expectations = Collections.synchronizedSet( new LinkedHashSet<>() );

        public Set<RequestExpectation> getExpectations() {
            return this.expectations;
        }

        public void update( RequestExpectation expectation ) {
            if ( expectation.hasRemainingCount() ) {
                getExpectations().add( expectation );
            } else {
                getExpectations().remove( expectation );
            }
        }

        public void updateAll( Collection<RequestExpectation> expectations ) {
            for ( RequestExpectation expectation : expectations ) {
                update( expectation );
            }
        }

        public RequestExpectation findExpectation( ClientHttpRequest request ) throws IOException {
            synchronized ( this.expectations ) {
                for ( RequestExpectation expectation : getExpectations() ) {
                    try {
                        expectation.match( request );
                        return expectation;
                    } catch ( AssertionError error ) {
                        // Ignore
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There are 2 notable things going on:

- first the commented lines in `RestRequestExpectationManager`, that makes us able to add expectations after the first request has been processed (not related to the ConcurrentModificationException issue at hand);
- then the `expectations` synchronization in `RestRequestExpectationManager.RequestExpectationGroup` in order to support async operations. Appears to be working for me.

Initialise the MockRestServiceServer as follows:

```
MockRestServiceServer mockRestServiceServer = MockRestServiceServer
            .bindTo( restTemplate )
            .build( new RestRequestExpectationManager() );
```

Answer (score 2):

I needed only the thread safety so I refactored [laur's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37815227/4494577) slightly and removed the other feature (modifying the expectations on-the-fly). Leaving it here for reference.

```
import org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpRequest;
import org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpResponse;
import org.springframework.test.web.client.AbstractRequestExpectationManager;
import org.springframework.test.web.client.RequestExpectation;
import org.springframework.test.web.client.UnorderedRequestExpectationManager;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

public class SynchronizedUnorderedRequestExpectationManager extends AbstractRequestExpectationManager {
    private final List<RequestExpectation> expectations = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList());
    private final List<ClientHttpRequest> requests = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList());
    private final SynchronizedRequestExpectationGroup remainingExpectations = new SynchronizedRequestExpectationGroup();

    @Override
    protected List<RequestExpectation> getExpectations() {
        return this.expectations;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ClientHttpRequest> getRequests() {
        return this.requests;
    }

    protected void afterExpectationsDeclared() {
        this.remainingExpectations.updateAll(this.getExpectations());
    }

    public ClientHttpResponse validateRequestInternal(ClientHttpRequest request) throws IOException {
        RequestExpectation expectation = this.remainingExpectations.findExpectation(request);

        if (expectation != null) {
            ClientHttpResponse response = expectation.createResponse(request);
            this.remainingExpectations.update(expectation);
            return response;
        }

        throw this.createUnexpectedRequestError(request);
    }

    public void reset() {
        super.reset();
        this.remainingExpectations.reset();
    }

    protected static class SynchronizedRequestExpectationGroup extends RequestExpectationGroup {

        private final Set<RequestExpectation> expectations = Collections.synchronizedSet(new LinkedHashSet<>());

        @Override
        public Set<RequestExpectation> getExpectations() {
            return this.expectations;
        }

        @Override
        public void updateAll(Collection<RequestExpectation> expectations) {
            synchronized (expectations) {
                super.updateAll(expectations);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public RequestExpectation findExpectation(ClientHttpRequest request) throws IOException {
            synchronized (expectations) {
                return super.findExpectation(request);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Background

The code is basically copied from [UnorderedRequestExpectationManager](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/client/UnorderedRequestExpectationManager.html). Unfortunately this is still necessary as the original class is tightly coupled to the [AbstractRequestExpectationManager.RequestExpectationGroup](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/client/AbstractRequestExpectationManager.RequestExpectationGroup.html) which is not thread safe. In order to replace the dependency this class needs to be rewritten. Other thread unsafe collection dependencies (from [AbstractRequestExpectationManager](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/client/AbstractRequestExpectationManager.html)) are replaced by overriding the [getExpectations](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/client/AbstractRequestExpectationManager.html#getExpectations--) and [getRequests](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/client/AbstractRequestExpectationManager.html#getRequests--) methods. Collection iterations are secured by critical sections.

### Usage

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
MockRestServiceServer mockServer = MockRestServiceServer.bindTo(restTemplate)
    .build(new SynchronizedUnorderedRequestExpectationManager());
```

Thanks laur! (upvoted)

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same issue with multiple threads using the RestTemplate / RestOperations object. It seems like the MockRestServiceServer is not properly thread safe.

I'm attempting to solve this right now, so far I've duplicated the MockRestService class and am trying CopyOnWriteArrayList for the expectedRequests and actualRequests. It seems to fix the problem but now my tests are failing.